# Special file being both a symlink and another type of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, symlink

I apologize if the question is lame. I am curious to know if there exists some special files that may be both a symbolic link as well as some other type of file? I tried creating a hidden symbolic file and it is possible. So, the file is a symlink as well as hidden (but I am afraid that's not a file type). Now, can I create a file being both a symbolic and some other file type? I'm sorry if I did not frame my question well.

Also, I am unsure if this question is supposed to be posted here. Please move it if necessary. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hidden" isn't a file type.  In Unix/Linux, the filesystem has no concept of a "hidden" file at all.  (By convention, many programs don't show files whose names begin with a dot, but that's just a naming convention implemented at the application layer.  As far as the OS is concerned, there's nothing special about a dot at the beginning of a filename.)

File types are things like:

- Regular file
- Symbolic link
- Directory
- Device file (block or character)
- Pipe
- Socket

Each entry in the filesystem can be only one of these types; it wouldn't make sense for something to be more than one.  The type determines what happens when you interact with the file (i.e. open it); if you had, say, a symbolic link that was also a directory, what would happen if you tried to read its contents?  Would you get the files in the directory, or the contents of whatever the symbolic link pointed to?

Comment: When I open the symlink in a vi editor I believe I get the directory listing (the symlink is pointed to that dir). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, vi recognizes that you're trying to open a directory and shows you its contents, and a symlink to a directory behaves like the directory it points to.  But the symlink itself is not a directory; it's just an alias for a directory that exists somewhere else.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, very much, for such a detailed answer. I appreciate it. I pointed a symlink to a dir before asking this stupid question here and tried to view its contents using less (which is wrong since I'm trying to less a dir. Stupid!), but was too dumb to figure out to open it using vi. Thank you, again. :)